# how to apply colormap to grayscale data, with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video, grayscale, colormap

I have a np.array with grayscale images and I want to apply a colormap, then save the result into a video file.

With this code (or with the commented line) I get a grayscale video anyways. Any idea why I can't have a colormap video?

```
color_images = np.empty([N, resolution[1], resolution[0], 3])
for i in range(0, N):
    cv2.imwrite(gray_images[i])
    color_images[i] = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(gray_images[i]), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    #color_images[i] = cv2.merge([gray_images[i], gray_images[i], gray_images[i]])
out = cv2.VideoWriter("video.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),
                      fps, (resolution[0], resolution[1]), 1)
for i in range(0, N):
    out.write(np.uint8(color_images[i]))
out.release()
```

UPDATE: I want to have a colored image so that differences in pixel intensity can be more noticeable. (For instance use the default cmap in plt.imshow ('viridis')).

Comment: What do you mean by you get a grayscale video? How do you determine that?

Comment: what do you expect? you have gray source data. do you want random colors to be introduced? -- you talk of colormaps. your code contains no attempt to use any. explain.

Comment: Just like when you use plt.imshow and the default cmap is colored scale ('viridis'), I want to have a similar output here so that differences in pixel intensity can be more noticeable. @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: @ypnos I have a black and white video and I want a colored one even though I only have one channel

Comment: there you go: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html -- you aren't gonna get color if you don't write code that produces the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cvtColor` doesn't do that. For any grayscale pixel, it gives you the RGB/BGR pixel that looks gray with the same intensity.

If you want colormaps, you need `applyColorMap`.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

gray_image = ... # get it from somewhere

colormapped_image = cv.applyColorMap(gray_image, cv.COLORMAP_JET)
```

[image: lena and COLORMAP_JET]

[learn more here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html#gadf478a5e5ff49d8aa24e726ea6f65d15)

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV (cv2) can apply a colormap to an image and save it. However, OpenCV's colormap functions expect the image data to be in 8-bit format, so you'll need to scale your normalized depth map to the range [0, 255] and convert it to an 8-bit format before applying the colormap.
So in case you have `floating point precision` data and you want to apply colormap on that use `matplotlib`. A simple use case

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Normalize the depth map
depth_map_normalized = np.clip(depth_map / 65000.0, 0, 1)

# Apply a colormap
depth_map_colored = cm.jet(depth_map_normalized)

# Save the result
plt.imsave('depth_map_colored.png', depth_map_colored)
```